# Excel VBA Auto-Save IF, THEN, ElSE

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make an Excel VBA macro to automate my saves. So if it is 2022 or 2023 and it is either the month of January, February, march, etc. The file will save in that year's folder and under that month's folder. However, I'm not the best at `If`, `Then`, `Else` statements. I made this VBA and it doesn't work after I tried to make it create folders if they don't exist.

```
Sub auto-organize-save()
'
' auto-organize-save Macro
'

'
    'this is for date
    Dim dateOne As Date
    'This is for making new folder
    Dim fdObj As Object
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set fdObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
         
    If fdObj.FolderExists("C:\temp\april") Then
    If dateOne = April Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\temp\april\save3.xlsx", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    Else
    fdObj.CreateFolder ("C:\temp\april")
    
    End If
    End If
End Sub
```

i modified it a bit further and I'm getting results but i need to figure out how to change the name of the folder to display the following:
"04 - APR" - 4 means the 4th month and APR is the abbreviated version. With the help of the user trincot following works perfectly.

```
 Sub auto_organize_save1()
    Dim fdObj As Object
    Dim folder As String
    
    Set fdObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    folderYear = "C:\temp\" & Format(Now, "YYYY") & "\"
    folderMonth = "C:\temp\" & Format(Now, "YYYY") & "\" & Format(Now, "MM-MMM") & "\"
    
    
    
    If Not fdObj.FolderExists(folderYear) Then
        MkDir folderYear
    End If
    
    If Not fdObj.FolderExists(folderMonth) Then
        MkDir folderMonth
    End If
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=folderMonth & "example2.xlsx"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Do not confuse VBScript with VBA, this is VBA code using the File Scripting Library from the Scripting Runtime Components, this doesn't make it a VBScript.

Comment: i apologize. i edited my question

Comment: Are you using VBA inside Excel or are you writing VBScript, the code looks like VBA so why have you edited the question and added VBS / VBScript back in? The code the methods you are using are not VBScript they are VBA.

Comment: You always want to name the file "save3"? And when you speak of the date, do you mean the *current* date, the creation date, last modification date, ...?

Comment: no save3 was just my third attempt at writing the code and testing. and i mean current date

Comment: It is somewhat disturbing that you took my code into your question. It makes my answer irrelevant. Please remove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- Your code is not getting a particular date, it just uses the default value of `dateOne`. Instead use `Now`.
- `dateOne = April` references an undefined variable `April`. In order to get the month of a date, use the `Month` function, and compare it with a number.
- Hard coding months, like "April", is not going to give you elegant code. Moreover, this is not even the format you are asking for ("4 - APR").
- I would suggest to prefix the month 4 with a zero so it always has two digits, and will look better when other entries are "12 - DEC", ...etc.
- `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` should only be used when you already have well working code. Don't use it for as long your code is not working. And if you use it, add also the opposite: `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`
- I'm not sure it is a good idea to call your file always "save3", but as I got no information about this aspect, I just left it as you had it.

Here is some code you could use:

```
Sub auto_organize_save()
    Dim fdObj As Object
    Dim folder As String
    
    Set fdObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    folder = "C:\temp\" & Format(Now, "MM-MMM") & "\"
    
    If Not fdObj.FolderExists(folder) Then
        MkDir folder
    End If
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=folder & "save3.xlsx"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: this is wayy cleaner than mine and i see how you structured it. omg thank you!! i over complicated it

Comment: it works originally but when i run it again it gives me a "run time error 75 path/file access error"

Comment: Did you debug? What is the path at that moment (put a break point) and what is the file structure? The script hardcodes "C:\temp\" which must exist... Just let me know what the situation is (file structure versus value of `folder`)

Comment: So im getting the error code under the first IF statement. this is the line that gets highlighted during debugging "MkDir folderYear" the issue only occurs when the folders exist, when they don't exist it runs perfectly

i updated the the post to display the code

Comment: What is the value of `folderYear`? I cannot reproduce this error in the scenario you give.

Comment: i was trying to tell the code to: 
1) create a folder named this current year and then 
2) in side that year folder create the month if it isnt created and then 
3) save the file inside that folder

Comment: i apologies, i modified it as you specified and it works perfectly. Your answer is extremely sophisticated. i really appreciate you